# Track Network send / receive data

Tags: networking

Suppose a website is loaded completely. Website is in HTTP version and has contact form. When we submit form, ajax is used to send the data. Page is neither refreshed. I want to track what data the website send from my browser to its server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two applications that immediately spring to mind that will enable you to monitor and also change http(s) traffic that travels through your browser.

- **[Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com)**
- **[Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/)**

In simple terms, they allow you to set up what is effectively a "man in the middle" style attack by way of a local proxy.

To quote the Burp Suite home page "An intercepting Proxy, which lets you inspect and modify traffic between your browser and the target application."

Both applications are quite mature and have great documentation on their respective sites.

There is also a really good playlist on Youtube by the developer of Fiddler2 that is well worth the time in checking out. The user name is Teleriklnc and the playlist is "Fiddler Web Debugging Proxy". (sorry no links, have reached my quota)

Further general reading on the topic - at the OWASP website.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome Man :) Loved your reply!

Comment: You are most welcome, you might also be interested in looking at [Samurai Web Testing Framework](http://samurai.inguardians.com/) - is a live linux environment that has been pre-configured to function as a web pen-testing environment. The CD contains the best of the open source and free tools that focus on testing your website for vulnerabilities. Enjoy!